# Why is there "Germany National Team", not "German National Team"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, toponyms

Why is the team from Germany called "Germany National Team", not "German National Team"? On official Internet sites, it is the same for every official national team; Germany National, France National, Poland National, Russia National etc. etc. What truthfully bothers me is why not *German*, *French*, *Polish*, *Russian* etc?

Comment: "Germany national team" is a modern trend seen often in newspapers, along with "German(y)-based company" instead of "German company". It's silly and no doubt not recommended by style books. Just stick to "German national team".

Comment: So, correct form is "German national team", yes?
English is not my mother tongue and for twenty years or so, I thought  that there is  "German national team".

Comment: Though Cerberus is entirely right, bear in  mind that 'the England team' is at least as common as 'the English team' in sports broadcasting.  Whether this depends on the country involved or on the sports broadcasters may provide a subject for a PhD thesis.

Comment: @lukasz: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So, there is no right answer for this question then?

Comment: @TimLymington: Right, so this is apparently common in sports broadcasting, too. But I think even that is more or less a fixed phrase? So *the England team*, but not **the England national team* or **the France team*, right? Or perhaps they use the whole spectrum of possibilities in sports broadcasting...?

Comment: @Cerberus
Before i post this question I've checked on the Internet.
Every official national team is called like this: Germany National, France National, Poland National, Russia National etc. etc. 
What truthfully bothers my is why not German, France, Polish, Russian etc?

Comment: @lukasz; *The German national team* is to be preferred to *the Germany national team*, and the same goes for most countries. There are shades of meaning between *England/France/Germany*, *the English/French/German team*, and *the England team*(/?*the France/Germany team*), that make it impossible to give a general answer, even without considering *the France/French players* or *the Germans' captain*.  The **formal title**, however, is more likely to be 'The Germany National team', since 'Germany' is a country not a team, and 'the German national team' is a description not a name.

Comment: I can't say I get it. 
So 'The Germany National team' is team which represents  Germany as a country. And it is it's formal title. 
'the German national team' is team which represents Germany as a country. But in this case it is pointed to that this one is  German,
 i.e. "This is German national team and that one is French" 
Am I right?

Comment: @lukasz: this is not a forum where you can keep asking supplementary questions, but a Q&A site where experts will give their considered opinion on the question as posed. The original was so simple it bordered on trivial. After your comments, I have edited it to what I think you meant to ask, which is actually quite interesting. Feel free to re-edit to make clear what you actually want to know; but each post should be only one question.

Comment: @TimLymington Thanks for re-edition. That is defiantly better asked question. And that is what  truthfully bothers me.

Comment: The ***correct form***, as witnessed by its official website, is the [Deutscher Fußball Bund](http://www.dfb.de) (which they translate as the [German football team](http://germany.worldcupblog.org/world-cup-2010/new-official-national-team-site.html)). The ***correct form*** of the England National football team (again witnessed by the website) is the [England football team](http://www.thefa.com/england). Why Wikipedia has been edited to read "the Germany National football team" is an interesting question.

Comment: @PeterShor: Right, but sports associations are not especially known for the quality of their writing style...I'm sure style books aren't too happy? So the answer to the question depends on "who's your peer group, and who do you want to please?".

Answer (score 2):

Germany National is the formal name, in English, of the team that represents the nation of Germany.  The phrase "German national team" is not the formal name, but describes the national team that represents Germany (and of course within Germany it is called the Deutscher Fussball Bund).

Germany National, England National, Spain National or [Country] National reflects the naming convention in use for the English language within the international football association.  Don't confuse naming convention with descriptive terms.  These are "Terms of Art", meaning they are artificial constructs or conventions, and are created for the purpose of consistency and recognition.

Germany National just happens to be the formal title of the German national football team - when spoken of *in English*.